# How do you customize Hover Box shapes in Wix?

Tags: velo

How do you customize the shape of the interactive hover box in Wix? I am wanting to make the box a 3 right angle pentagon with the other two angles the same degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donnie:

Take a look at these articles on the hover box.
https://support.wix.com/en/article/creating-hover-box-effects

You may be able to find a vectorArt image in the images collection that you can add to the hover box

- [Sample Vector Art Images Available on Wix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyjWo.png)

You simply select the Add Element Menu item and then Shapes and then the **"More Basic Shapes"** link...

- [Adding Shapes in the Wix Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A3oe.png)

Now if you cannot find the shape you need then one approach would be to either create an image using an application like power point and upload that. Alternatively if you can create/find an SVG image that meets your need you can also use that:

- [Adding SVG images using the Wix Editor](https://support.wix.com/en/article/information-and-guidelines-on-vector-art)